# How to check response of a URL in Python and store in DB?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Say I have about a 100,000 or more URLs for which I need to hit them and check for the response code.

Would the below work for such a big number or is there any other approach which is efficient?

1- import request
2- response = request.get('https://google.com')
3- print(response)

Also I have a DB table-

[image]

I want to store the tested URLs into that table. Again, my point is, what is the efficient way to do it for 100,000 URLs or even more.

Comment: How are the urls stored now? Storing the results on a db would be ideal for post processing, but a `csv` is also an option with way less work.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: @CONvid19, the URLs are stored as a string currently. When I run this python script, I wish to update the table again with the response code.

Comment: @BharathwajMurali Better use a DB, sqlite3 seems a good fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question may be lost forever in time, but it inspired me to code a simple spider.
It uses sqlite3 and its multi-threaded.

## setup_spider.py (run once)

```
import sqlite3
db_name = "spider.db"

# create sqlite3 db
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
c = conn.cursor() # The database will be saved in the location where your 'py' file is

# create the spider table if it doesn't exist
c.execute('''create table if not exists spider ([url] text PRIMARY KEY, [status] integer, [dt] date) ''')

# insert all urls to DB
# The folowing assumes the urls are on a text file one per line
with open("top100.txt") as f:  # https://gist.github.com/demersdesigns/4442cd84c1cc6c5ccda9b19eac1ba52b
    for url in f:
        c.execute(f""" INSERT OR IGNORE into spider (url) VALUES('{url.strip()}') """);

conn.commit()
conn.close()
print("Your spider was setup succesfully")
```

## spider.py

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import time
from  datetime import datetime
import threading
import traceback

# spider settings
db_name = "spider.db" # db name
spider_name = "Stack Spider" # spider name
spider_max_threads = 15 # max parallel threads. More threads doesn't mean faster crawling, adjust according to your OS and Network
spider_sleep = 0.05 # sleep time when max threads is reached
spider_allow_redirects = 1 # allow spider redirects - 0 to disable
spider_timeout = 5  # request timeout in secs
spider_ua = f"{spider_name} Crawler Bot" # spider User-Agent
spider_headers = {"User-Agent": spider_ua} # request headers
log_level = 0 # 0 disabled, 1 minimal, 2 errors

# insert on DB
def update_status(url, status, dt):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f""" INSERT or REPLACE into spider (url, status, dt) VALUES('{url}', '{status}', '{dt}') ; """);
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# crawler
def crawl(url):
    dt  = datetime.now()
    try:
        if log_level == 1: print(f"Crawling {url}")
        res = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=spider_allow_redirects, timeout=spider_timeout, headers=spider_headers)
        status = res.status_code
        update_status(url, status, dt)
        if log_level == 1: print(f"{url} {status}")
    except:
        pass
        update_status(url, 0, dt) # set status 0 if there was an error on the request (too many redirect, timeouts, etc)
        if log_level > 1: print("Error: ", traceback.print_exc())

# count spider threads
def count_threads():
    n = 0
    for x in threading.enumerate():
        if "spider" == x.getName():
            n+=1
    return n


# get all urls from DB
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT url FROM spider') # can be changed to filter the websites to crawl, eg: first 1000 urls or google and fb only, etc...
urls = c.fetchall()
conn.close()

# main loop
start = time.time()
print(f"{spider_name} Started. Crawling {len(urls)} urls")
for url in urls:
    threading.Thread(target=crawl, args=[url[0]], name="spider").start()
    while count_threads() >= spider_max_threads:
        time.sleep(spider_sleep)

# wait threads to finish
while count_threads():
    time.sleep(spider_sleep)
end = time.time()

print(f"{spider_name} Finished in {int(end - start)} seconds")
```

---

- [Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/0556f7417b)
- Feedback is welcome!

Comment: Making a large number of network requests in a for loop might not be the best way to go about it.

Comment: I'm actually creating small spider for this answer using multi-thread and a sqlite3 db, which I'll post after. Tks for your insights!

Comment: @uglyCoder It's _ready_,  you can take it for a ride when the quarantine is over  ;)

Comment: Do you reckon Spider is a better option? Why not Python?

Comment: @BharathwajMurali I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand your comment, can you  please rephrase it?

Comment: Okay. So, can't this problem statement be handled using a conventional python script? I am not familiar with Spider. An approach using the regular python would highly help! :D TIA.

Comment: ah! this is all python 3.6, I just called it a spider :) Check the demo .  You may want to get https://sqlitebrowser.org/  to view the DB. To use your URLS, change `top100.txt` to your lists, one per line.

Comment: @BharathwajMurali, If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to loop over 100k or more urls, and then get response stored in your database sequentially. A better way is to use aiohttp.It is Asynchronous HTTP Client/Server for asyncio and Python.
You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/) and documentation [here](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Also, try to populate your db with all the responses in one query, by first maintaining a list of all responses and then doing a bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do is by using SOAPUI tool. There are test steps to loops through any data source(JSON,.csv,excel, Database etc.) for the requests and dump the response to database table.This requires no coding ,just some fiddling with tool should help you to achieve. I am not sure if this would help.